# web2py: crud form to edit users resets password

Tags: web2py

I have a crud form so an administrator can edit users. The administrator needs to be able to change the password if necessary. I am using:

```
crud.update(db.auth_user, user_id, deletable=False)
```

to create the form and it works fine if I type in the password. But if I don't want to change the password, it resets the password and the user is unable to log in. It looks like the password field is being updated with the crypted version and causing it to reset. How can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

can you remove the variable from form.vars if it's empty or invalid? Since web2py has so much auth stuff integrated, I've never actually messed with password field stuff, but this might work.

You can use `crud.update(..., onvalidation=somefunction)` and have somefunction check for a valid value in the password field, if it doesn't find it, `del form.vars.password`? or set form.vars.password to None perhaps?

onvalidation will happen AFTER the form is accepted (validated) but BEFORE the values are entered/updated in the database.